# AdMob Mediation Different SDK

Tags: android, admob

i have AdMob mediation activated with Inmobi as second SDK.

i have the function:

```
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.i("MyDays Ads", "--------  AdmobMedi Banner Ad found");

        }
```

how could i find out if a inmobi banner is shown or a admob banner.
For now the above function is triggered for both adnetworks.

thanks
chris

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to tell programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. During mediation Adview receives adapter according to the ad network which won the auction(you can see that in logs with "Ad" tag). In your on AdReceived you can call AdView.getMediationAdapterClassName() described here:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.html#getMediationAdapterClassName()
That will tell you which ad network will show the ad.